# Passing a variable from multiple classes to a function

Tags: c++, function, class, object, variables

I'm making a simple game of catching the fruit, but I've been having troubles with the collision logic and/or using the variables from the classes.

```
class row
{
public:
int x,y;
    void setpoint (int xi, int yi)
    {
        x=xi;
        y=yi;
    }

float DownSpeed = 5;
void down () {

    y = y+DownSpeed;

    if (y==1000) {
            y=0;
        }
    }
};


class fruit:public row
{
public:
void draw()
{
    setcolor(11);
    circle(x,y,20);
}
};
```

Then I have other classes to create the catcher, like so:

```
class catcher
{
protected:

float moveSpeed = 5;

public:

float catchX, catchY;
void setpoint (int xi, int yi)
    {
        catchX=xi;
        catchY=yi;
    }
void MoveLeft () {
    catchX = catchX - moveSpeed;}

void MoveRight () {
    catchX = catchX + moveSpeed;}

};

class character:public catcher
{
public:
void draw()
{
    setcolor(15);
    circle(catchX,catchY,50);
}
};
```

How do I call the variables of both circles into creating a collision function? I'm sorry if the codes are messy and ineffective, I'm just starting out and I'm stuck. Thanks!

Comment: How are you *using* these classes? You currently have no objects, only definitions

Answer (score 0):

Since both sets of variables are in the public part of the class, you should be able to create a function independent of either class and should be able to access the variables as long as they are declared.

```
void CheckCollision(float x, float y, float catchX, float catchY)
{
    If(y =< catchY + 5)
    {
        //y resets
    }
}
```

You’d want to check if it’s within a certain x range too though. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I still can't get it to work. I declare x, y, catchX, and catchY as a, b, c, d respectively, insert some numbers to the new variables and use it to A.setpoint (for the fruit) and CH.setpoint (for the catcher) like this : A.setpoint(a, b). Then I use a b c d to the collision func, yet it still doesn't work. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since all the functions and variables are public. return the values of x, catchX from the functions modifying them. use the draw functions after you have the modified values.

for example modify your down function like this

```
int down()
{
    y = y+DownSpeed;

    if (y==1000) 
    {
        y=0;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Modify the other function like wise and you will end up having your x,y and catchX, catchY values. create you collison function with these values.